# Who are the primary users of Internet Explorer <= 8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser, compatibility

tl; dr: making website for biological researchers. Are these guys apt to use IE8?

I'm developing a website that will act as a reference for biology researchers. I'd like to implement loads of HTML5 and CSS3 if I can. But I can't spend forever developing it though, and fixing websites for IE8 takes too long, especially with the heavy reliance on SVG elements I have planned. With such a user base (researchers), would it be safe to drop support for IE8 and below? I've heard that it's mostly banks and airline companies that use IE <= 8, but I've never come across an actual statistic, other than that global usage of IE8 is around 10%, which is a bit high for my taste.

Comment: I don't think "researchers" all get together and decide what browser to use.  You'll have to ask those specific researchers what browser they use; or, just say, my "latest and greatest" software requires X browser...

Comment: I suggest you ask them...

Comment: I'm more or less asking who makes up the primary user base for IE8.

Comment: Anyone who has Windows XP or Windows 7 and doesn't know what a browser is. Or people who think that IE = "The Internet"

Comment: The main users are the ones that do not know what Google Chrome and Mozilla FireFox are.

Comment: All the ones who double click on the blue e

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, of course, "it depends", but some things you might consider:

**-Who benefits from people using your site?** If it's you who wants them to use it, then the onus is more on you to make their lives easier by supporting whatever browser they use (most ecommerce sites would fit this category).  If there's less value to you and you're genuinely just trying to be helpful by producing a valuable tool for you particular research community, it'd probably be more reasonable to expect them to update if they care enough.

**-How much effort would support be?** If it's little extra effort, then just do it, but for what you've described it sounds like support would be very difficult. If it's going to take 5 times as long to support 10% more people, I personally wouldn't bother.

**-What sort of age are they?** Not always true, but generally speaking younger people will tend to use more recent browsers.

In your position, I'd try to ask 10 or so people who you'd expect to use the site what browser they use. If only 1 or 2 people would be affected, I'd ditch IE8 support, and make sure the site falls gracefully back to a page explaining why they aren't able to use it and how to update their browser.

Answer (score 1):

Points to consider:

- Many people who use IE8 may also have other browsers installed *as well*. (choice of browser isn't an 'either-or' option)
- How about making your site semi-functional for IE8 rather than entirely non-functional? If parts of it don't work, explain that to the user, but don't stop them using the bits that could work for them.
- There are fall-back options (polyfills) for IE8 that allow you to do some modern browser features, including SVG -- [see here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#svg). They won't work as well as modern browser, but they might make it possible to support IE8 a bit more than you think, without too much extra work on your part.
- If your resource is useful enough, and the IE8 users can see what they're missing, it might push people to upgrade in order to use it.
- Surely a group of intelligent people (scientists, researchers) would be sufficiently technically literate that they'd at least know about alternative browsers, even if they are still using an old PC that originally came with IE8. With luck, your target market may have fewer IE8 users than the general population.